# Click on element by name instead of id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I'm trying to get a few lines of code to click checkbox and button in a website.
the elements on the website are shown as following:

```
<td>
    <label style="display: block; cursor: pointer">
        <input type=radio name="business_9942704" value="2"> Banking Now Inc.
    </label>
</td>

<input type="submit" value="Commit!">
```

So what it needs to do it click on the name "business_9942704" and then click on the value Commit!

I have tried multiple things but I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, my code looks like this:

```
document.getElementByName('business_9942704').click(); 
document.getElementByValue('Commit!').click();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any of the methods you've tried doesn't exist. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Answer (score 1):

there is not a function
    getElementByName

but

```
getElementsByName
```

please take a look in the console to see errors, don't program in blind mode

Answer (score 0):

Correct method is `document.getElementsByName('business_9942704')[0].click();`

But this method return array of element you need use index for them.